# Service Stack Injecting and Resolving Service in Filter (dot net core 2)

Tags: asp.net-core, filter, dependency-injection

I have a TypeFilterAtrribute which instantiates and ActionFilter. The ActionFilter needs two services injected.

```
 public class ValidateUserAttribute : TypeFilterAttribute
{
    public ValidateUserAttribute() : base(typeof(AuthenticationFilter))
    {
    }


    private class AuthenticationFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        private readonly IActiveDirectoryService ActiveDirectoryService;
        private readonly MessageService MessageSerivce;
        public AuthenticationFilter(IActiveDirectoryService activeDirectoryService, MessageService messageSerivce)
        {
            ActiveDirectoryService = activeDirectoryService;
            MessageSerivce = messageSerivce;
        }
```

I have it working with the default IOC container of dot net core 2 but I could not use Funq container to do it.

I am reading from appsettings.json (I think I read on the docs ServiceStack does not support this) and registering

```
 var config = Configuration.GetSection("LdapAuth");
 services.Configure<LdapAuthenticationOptions>(Configuration.GetSection("LdapAuth"));
 services.AddActiveDirectoryService(options =>
            Configuration.GetSection("LdapAuth"));//uses collection.AddTransient<IActiveDirectoryService, ActiveDirectoryService>()
services.AddMessageService(); //same as above
```

I can't think of a way to inject into the filter a parameterized service.

So this does not work at all because I don't have a default constructor.

```
public class AuthenticationFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
public IActiveDirectoryService ActiveDirectoryService {get; set;};
```

But this below at least should have worked. I'm not using an interface here though.
     public class AuthenticationFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
    public MessageService MessageService{get; set}; //notice not using interface here although this as default constructor.

Where this gets really ugly is then I have controllers that inherit ServiceStackController and I inject services using ResolveService from the Funq container.

```
  public class MessageController : ServiceStackController
{
...
var messageService = ResolveService<MessageService>()
```

I re-register them.. like below.

```
  public override void Configure(Funq.Container container)
    {
        SqlServerDialect.Provider.RegisterConverter<TimeSpan>(new ServiceStack.OrmLite.SqlServer.Converters.SqlServerTimeConverter
        {
            Precision = 7
        });

        var connectionString = GetConnectionString(AppSettings);

        container.Register<IDbConnectionFactory>(
            new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(connectionString, new SqlServerOrmLiteDialectProvider()));

        LdapAuthenticationOptions options = GetLdapAuthenticationOptions(AppSettings); //notice now I have to read from AppSetting.. which is appsettings.txt file.

        container.Register(c => new ActiveDirectoryService(options));
        container.Register(c => new MessageService());
    }
```

Comment: It's not clear what the actual question is? but .NET Core's IOC cannot see dependencies registered in Func IOC (but [ServiceStack can see dependencies registered in .NET Core's ConfigureServices](http://docs.servicestack.net/netcore#net-core-container-adapter)). So any .NET Core dependencies need to be registered in .NET Core's `ConfigureServices()`

Comment: I do not want .NET Core's IOC to register any dependency - for controller or filters. I have registered services for controllers with Funq and same services for action filter with .dot net core's because I could not find a way to do this with Funq.

Comment: Funq is for registering dependencies for ServiceStack Services. You need to use .NET Core's IOC for any .NET Core / MVC features like MVC Controllers or MVC Filters.

Comment: ok fair enough. If you don't mind answering this,  Db.SingleWhere<T> does not load references whereas Db.LoadSingleById<T>. Is there any reason for this? I need to make a second call to db to fetch reference with the former.

Comment: Only [Load* APIs load references](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite#querying-pocos-with-references)